# Getting more precise location

Tags: android, google-location-services

In my Android Application I am targeting the device ranging from,

*Minimum Android Version - 7.1  (API 25)*

*Target Android Version - 10.0 (API 29)*

I am using the below logic to get the location Information

**Permissions Using**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Code Logic**

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         network_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (gps_loc != null) {
            final_loc = gps_loc;
            latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
        }
        else if (network_loc != null) {
            final_loc = network_loc;
            latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
        }
        else {
            latitude = 0.0;
            longitude = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

But most of the time I am not getting accurate location with API call. But If enable the below option in device level (in Phone), I am getting the most accurate location

[image]

Is there any way I can configure the above settings in application level through code. The client which I am working is not satisfied with changing the configuration manually.

I am wondering how I can achieve the same through code. Someone please help.

Answer (score -2):

Somethings you should know about `getLastKnownLocation(...)` `[From Document]`

Gets the last known location from the given provider, or null if there is no last known location. The returned location may be quite old in some circumstances, so the age of the location should always be checked.

This will never activate sensors to compute a new location, and will only ever return a cached location.

---

Please try `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(...)`, this method will request user current location.

```
if(locationManager.allProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locListener)
} else if(locationManager.allProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
    locationManager.rerequestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locListener)
}
```

And this is listener.

```
val locListener = object: LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
            // do something with updated location here.
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }
```

Comment: answer is not relevant to the question, he was asking about enabling wifi scanning of Google location service through code.

Comment: This does make some sense though as when you are just relying on `getLastKnownLocation()` you have no control on the accuracy, but if you request a location update (or continuous location updates) you can specify which providers to use etc.

Comment: From the questuin, I think that what he want is precise location so I advice hime to use `requestSingleUpdate(...)` since it helps to get current location while `getLastKnownLocation(...)` not really get current location and sometime it can even be null. And when use `getLastKnownLocation(...)`, it's not even need you to turn on location. So how you can get precise location without turn on location service.